# CSP issue: use of SVG blocked because not recognized

Tags: apache, content-security-policy

I have set a strict CSP in my .htaccess to only allow content from a list of domains.

Example:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 
  https://*.mydomain.com
```

I would like to use a SVG technique to prevent image reflow, it consists in using something like this:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
  viewBox='0 0 3 2'%3E%3C/svg%3E" data-src="//picsum.photos/900/600" 
  alt="Lazy loading test image" />
```

The src is blocked by the CSP and I don't know how I could modify the CSP in order to allow this. I have tried to use something like data:image/svg+xml* but it's ignored.

Do you have any idea of how I could make this work?

Thanks

Laurent

Answer (score 0):

> The src is blocked by the CSP and I don't know how I could modify the
> CSP in order to allow this.

Just add the `data:` scheme to your CSP

> Do you have any idea of how I could make this work?

<s>You have a wrong `src=` in the construct:</s>

```
<img
  src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 3 2'%3E%3C/svg%3E"
  data-src="//picsum.photos/900/600"
  alt="Lazy loading test image" />
```

sorry, construct is correct, it was my mistake. I was confused that `src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'` is not looks like real data:-URL.
Anyway you need to have `img-src data:` (or `default-src data:` in your case) to allow data:-Urls for images.

But `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: https://*.mydomain.com` will allow `data:` for scripts too - it's unsafe. Therefore

```
default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.mydomain.com;
img-src 'self' data: https://*.mydomain.com;
```

is a little bit safer.